# What is the geometric interpretation of $\displaystyle\lim _{s\to 1}\sin²(\zeta(s))+\cos²(\zeta(s)) $?

Tags: limits, continuity, geometric-interpretation

it's seems that $\displaystyle\lim _{s\to 1}\sin²(\zeta(s))+\cos²(\zeta(s)) $ dosn't exist as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim(sin%C2%B2(+zeta(s))%2Bcos%C2%B2(zeta(s))),+s+to+1) by wolfram alpha , and because $\zeta(1)$ is undefined , My question is to seek if the titled equation has any geometric interpretation .

> > **Question:**
> >     What is the geometric interpretation of this :  $\displaystyle\lim _{s\to 1}\sin²(\zeta(s))+\cos²(\zeta(s)) $ ?

**Note:**$\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function

Comment: Wolfram Alpha doesn't "show" any such thing. $\sin^2 z + \cos^2 z = 1$ for all $z$, so This expression is $\lim_{s\to 1} 1=1$.

Comment: This is one of those problems where using Wolfram Alpha is silly, and it gives you the wrong answer. The expression you have is always 1, due to the trigonometric identity $\sin^2 z + \cos^2 z = 1$, so the limit is 1. Not sure what you mean by geometric interpretation.

Comment: Is lim (sin z), z to infty exist ?

Comment: No, that limit does not exist. @YoussraElYossraYoussra

Comment: then how you claimed that limit is 1 ? howver sinz and cosz undefined at infty ?

Comment: $\lim_{z\to\infty} \sin(z)+(1-\sin(z))$ is also $1$. Limits have nothing to do with whether the function is defined at the point you are approaching.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for $s \ne 1$, it is trivially true that $\cos^2 \zeta(s) + \sin^2 \zeta(s) = 1$ simply becaused $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$. Since $\zeta$ is not defined in $s = 1$, then $\cos^2 \zeta(s) + \sin^2 \zeta(s) = 1$ is not defined in $s=1$ either. It follows that $\lim _{s \to 1} \cos^2 \zeta(s) + \sin^2 \zeta(s) = \lim _{s \to 1} 1 = 1$, while $\cos^2 \zeta(1) + \sin^2 \zeta(1)$ simply does not exist.

The situation is like the following: consider $f : \Bbb R \setminus \{0\} \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = \frac 1 x$, and $g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $g(x) = 1$. One has that $\lim _{x \to 0} (g \circ f) (x) = \lim _{x \to 0} 1 = 1$, but $(g \circ f) (1)$ does not exist.